# How to send an internal transaction without fees in Ethereum

Tags: curl, ethereum, web3js

How can I send an internal transaction without fees in Ethereum (using Web3 or Curl Method)

I've tried with the below code, but it doesn't work

```
var tx = {from: "0x391694e7e0b0cce554cb130d723a9d27458f9298", to: "0xafa3f8684e54059998bc3a7b0d2b0da075154d66", value: web3.toWei(1.23, "ether")}
personal.sendTransaction(tx, "passphrase")
```

Comment: Not possible. You need gas (ETH).

Comment: But i'm asking for internal transfer (Between my accounts in my wallet)

Answer (score 0):

Ethereum treats every account as an island. There is no link between the addresses of an MD wallet like in Bitcoin. This might be the confusion. In other words: in Ethereum, there is no UTXO

Internal transactions in Ethereum are transactions created in a smart-contract.

you tx object is well formatted. Note that the `from` account will be billed some gas.

in order to send the transaction, you have to first `unlock` the `from` account with `web3.personal.unlockAccount("0x..", "<passs>", 1000);` and then you can `web3.eth.sendTransaction(tx)`

this will work for example in a geth console `geth attach http://your.eth.node:port`

Comment: Its an normal flow.. it works for me with transaction fees.. I need to transact between my wallet address. So i need to integrate internal transaction. But i don't know how to make a internal transactions.Kindly help me to figure out this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: please be more explicit. What is it you're trying to achieve? As I mentioned above, an internal transaction in Ethereum is not the same as Bitcoin.

Comment: in your Ethereum HD Wallet each address is an independent account. It is not possible to transfer from one address derived from the seed to another address derived from the seed. please see my answer update